# When I see a black pixel only on a blue screen, is that a stuck pixel or dead pixel?

Tags: lcd, dead-pixel, stuck-pixel

I have pixel on my LCD that appears black only on a blue background; it works fine on other colors.

[image: Black LCD Pixel]

Is this a "stuck pixel" or "dead pixel"?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Dead.

Stuck is ON, dead is OFF.

Pixels are created from sub-pixels of primary colors, typically red, green, and blue:

[image]

The reason the dead spot is visible only when blue is displayed is because it is a blue sub-pixel that is dead. When the background is blue, that is the only color on, and it stands out. When the background is another color, the other sub-pixels reproduce it or it is still bright and absent blue, which is less noticeable.

For example, you can see yellow because it is created from red plus green.  A white pixel with a dead blue sub-pixel will produce yellow, which isn't very noticeable in a bright spot that small.

There is a guide at [digitaltrends.com](http://www.digitaltrends.com/mobile/how-to-fix-a-dead-pixel/) for various methods of attempting DIY fixes for stuck or dead pixels - though it must be noted that it's
a) very hit & miss &
b) potentially damaging to the rest of your screen if attempted too enthusiastically.

Comment: and why it only appears on blue and works just fine on red , yellow , white , etc?

Comment: @Mirkan: Because it is a blue sub-pixel that is dead.  When the background is blue, that is the only color on, and it stands out.  When the background is another color, the other sub-pixels reproduce it or it is still bright and absent blue, which is less noticeable.

Comment: You'd find on white that your dead pixel would actually be yellow [ie, red+green] though it would be hard to spot