# Strange Issue with Monitor - Single Pixel Line in only Certain Colours

Tags: display, colors, lcd

I am using a [B156HAN01.2](http://www.panelook.com/B156HAN01.2_AUO_15.6_LCM_overview_19049.html) screen in a Lenovo Y50-70 (Win10x64)

With certain colours (blue, #0075AF is a good colour to see the line) displayed, I can see what I presume a single pixel line going downwards. It doesn't seem to be composed of dead pixels, as it seems to be partially lit, kinda fades in and out. (Not dynamically, just isn't a solid line)

I have run various stuck pixel fixes, nothing seems to make much difference. I have tried different programs, so it's a hardwear issue for sure.

I have no clue, has anyone any idea?

Comment: It's possibly connectivity at the screen edge - but note that 'dead' pixels & 'stuck' pixels are polar opposites, even though the end result is "a pixel doesn't work as intended". See http://superuser.com/a/889264/347380 for a related answer, to not necessarily the same symptom.

Comment: Conversely, most of these pixels are neither dead nor stuck, yet they are never going to work again, because the circuit has been broken [badly] - http://superuser.com/questions/987806/monitor-wasnt-damaged-but-a-white-irregular-shape-covers-more-than-half-of-the#comment1361012_987806

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had this happen with my laptops before.  It's probably the connection between the screen and the laptop base.  For me it only got worse as I used my laptop more and more.  To confirm it is not your graphics chip in your laptop connect it to an external monitor.  If you do not see the line, then that will confirm it has nothing to do with your graphics processor.  Solution: Take the laptop to a hardware specialist to fix it.

Comment: I replaced the screen myself, I know how to replace it easily. I'll check the connection (EDP) is a-OK.