# Is this a dead pixel on my new screen?

Tags: display, dead-pixel

I have a dot on my screen that looks a bit like an anti-aliased circle. I took a picture of it:

[image]

To me it looks like it's not only one pixel that's dead, but a whole bunch 
but they're also not completely black.

It's very noticeable on a white background (obviously) and it doesn't really change depending on the foreground. I tried running [JScreenFix](http://www.jscreenfix.com/) over it and it didn't help.

It's also visible when the screen is showing a white background due to "no signal".

I got the screen only yesterday (it's an LG 27UD58), should I take it back or is there a way to fix this myself?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: related but not an exact dupe - https://superuser.com/questions/889262/when-i-see-a-black-pixel-only-on-a-blue-screen-is-that-a-stuck-pixel-or-dead-pi/889264#889264

Comment: It looks more like an tiny LED backlight has died rather than an LCD pixel. either that or there is a bit of dirt/debris behind the LCD layer.

Comment: tbh, without any other visual clues, it's hard to tell whether the dot is smooth or the picture is out of focus.

Comment: As it's a new display I would take it back and exchange it.

Answer (score 3):

This is dust between LCD screen and backlight plane.

The grid pattern shown in the picture actually shows the pixels, so the dark spot is much larger than a pixel. Also, pixels are squared, not round.

This also can't be a defect LED as stated in the comment, because  the spot still is very small and has quite sharp borders. How many LEDs should the display have, and how to lit the display evenly, if a single LED would lit only such a small area with that borders?

My display is full of such spots. Some are circles, some look more like a small hair, or even a bunch of fibers. This is dust.