# Is it a dead pixel or stuck pixel or pressure mark?

Tags: lcd

I have some small light spots on my LCD that never go away.

On black, I don't see any spots.

On any other color—for example if it is a red background—I see faint red color on those spots location.

So is it a dead pixel or stuck pixel? FWIW, this happened just after cleaning the LCD with a cloth while it is turned on.

Here is a picture of my screen. The bright spot is on the right:
[image: The bright spot is on the right]

Comment: Can you share a photo? Is it a single pixel, multiple pixels, or a smudge / mark on the panel?

Comment: Screenshots do not capture problems with the LCD panel, because the problem is on the panel, not the image being sent to it by the computer. Use a camera to take a picture of the pixel in question and attach THAT image to this question please.

Comment: @Attie i included screenshots

Comment: @music2myyear ,there is nothing wrong with the panel as far as i can see , it has not even been scratched

Comment: @Girl - as per music2myear's comment, please post a decent photo (in focus, and well lit) that shows the issue. If we're going by screen shots then the best I can say is... there isn't a problem! (screenshots are perfect, and my screen is clean and without issues)

Comment: Please also check or share a photo with the panel turned off to see if the mark / blemish / problem persists.

Comment: You misunderstood: A pixel can become dead/stuck without any visible physical damage.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When I see a black pixel only on a blue screen, is that a stuck pixel or dead pixel?](https://superuser.com/questions/889262/when-i-see-a-black-pixel-only-on-a-blue-screen-is-that-a-stuck-pixel-or-dead-pi)

Comment: @Tetsujin, it is not a duplicate, my case is different, i have faint spot on every background color , whether it is red or green or blue or whatever

Comment: @Attie , i now included picture of my laptop screen , i hope it is clear :D

Comment: @Attie also the screenshots can provide better vision , but only if you opened the picture to be full screen

Comment: @Girl I think what is being requested is perhaps a picture taking with a cell phone camera or a digital camera so we can see what you are seeing when you view images via your LCD. A screenshot of red or white will always be pure since the screenshot is a representation of what the computer is intending to display, no what you are actually seeing through the display itself.

Comment: @jakeGould yeah , i now included photo of my actual screen , it is the best quality i can get , so sorry if it is not that clear

Comment: Now that you have posted an actual picture of the screen, that looks like a “blemish” which is hard to diagnose if we are not actually viewing the screen itself. Maybe cleaner did something? I doubt it. Can you turn off the display and just clean it again but with just a cloth dampened in water?

Comment: I'm assuming that the issue you're referring to is the series of "bubbles" of brightness roughly 1/4 of the way down from the top of the image and 1/3 of the way across from the right edge?  If so, those aren't pixels or subpixels, they're some form of damage to the screen (likely pressure damage or bubbles of separation between layers).  There is no practical way to fix those kinds of problems.  It may be distracting because you're aware of it, but if the screen is still usable, just choose to ignore it.  The alternative is to replace the screen.

Answer (score 2):

A "dead" pixel is one that is turned off and will not turn on. So it is always black.

Any pixel that is some color other than black and remains a consistent color other than the color it is supposed to be displaying is "stuck".

Other issues, such as inaccurate color or light levels in a pixel of group of pixels indicates some other problem with the panel.

None of these visible issues will be captured by a screenshot because the screenshot only captures an image of the information being sent to the screen by the computer, and all of these issues are with the screen itself and the computer has no way to know about them.

All of these issues indicate a problem with the panel, the physical screen itself. Some of them COULD be repaired using the tips mentioned in the question linked in the comments above, but many of them cannot be repaired.

Answer (score 1):

It's very difficult to say exactly what the issue is without seeing the panel in person. However, I expect it would be one of the following issues - all of which are physical damage. I'd vote for #1.

1. The panel has been physically hit / damaged from the rear, causing the layers to become malformed. This effect can happen if the "*Bottom Chassis*" becomes dented and applies constant pressure to the rear of the panel.
2. The front surface (possibly even the polarizer itself) has been physically damaged or had a substance deposited on it. If your cleaning was particularly vigorous or the solution you used affected the panel, then it's entirely possible that the matt finish of the panel could have been reduced, or conversely could have collected additional material. Try "*huffing*" on the panel and wiping it away with a [microfiber cloth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microfiber).
3. The panel has got moisture inside it, most likely between the reflector, light guide, diffuser and prism sheets, but also potentially at the front. As the layers of the panel are so close together, it's possible for moisture to get quite a long way into the panel by [capillary action](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capillary_action). Did you use a liquid cleaner, and did any drops make their way to the edges of the panel?

This diagram from [Samsung](https://pid.samsungdisplay.com/en/learning-center/blog/lcd-structure) shows the layers in a modern LCD:

[image: LCD layers]

---

From the photo you've shared it definitely isn't a [dead or stuck pixel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Defective_pixel) or any other LCD defect, as this would typically be only one pixel (or sub-pixel, or row / column) in size, and would have sharp edges with dramatic color changes.

Comment: yeah i used liquid cleaner, and i too doubt that some drops have leaked into the panel.
can i do anything about it for now if it is the case?

Comment: unfortunately removing moisture from a panel is a fiddly and error-prone job... even if you're very competent, you'll likely make it worse.

Comment: okay ,is there any hope that it will go away on its own on the long run?

Comment: Sadly it's not likely... Moisture is almost certainly going to stay there... though you could try a sunny day. If the back of the panel is dented, then try removing the dent.

Comment: That’s a lot of sheets right there.